# how to write extend network prefix?

Tags: hosts, subnet

I need help with this:

Assume that you have been assigned the 200.35.1.0 /24  network block
Define an extended network prefix that allows the creation of 20 hosts on each subnet.

I've written the addresses in binary form: 
IP:    1100 1000 . 0010 0011 . 0000 0001 . 0000 0000
Mask:  1111 1111 . 1111 1111 . 1111 1111 . 0000 0000

extended network prefix must be:

New Mask: 1111 1111 . 1111 1111 . 1111 1111 . xxxx xxxx

I know that 2^value - 2 = subnets
But how do you know how many it requires? The subnets are not given.. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The next largest power of 2 from the required 20 hosts is 32.
2. 32 is 2^5.
3. There are 32 bits in an address or mask.
4. 32 bits for the mask size - 5 bits for the subnet size = 27 bits for the mask length
5. A 27-bit mask is 11111111.11111111.11111111.11100000
6. Take the original subnet, AND it with your mask to get the first subnet
7. Add 32 for each successive subnet
8. Convert the binaries back to decimal